# Passing a setting into a function in Wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a PHP function in Wordpress that renders a different badge based on a user's membership type.

```
function get_membership_badge() {
  $user_id = bbp_get_user_id();
  $membership_level = rcp_get_subscription($user_id);

  if ($membership_level === 'Community') {
    echo '';
  }

  elseif ($membership_level === 'Supporter') {
    echo '<span class="member-badge supporter small">Supporter</span>';
  }

  elseif ($membership_level === 'Professional') {
    echo '<span class="member-badge pro small">Pro</span>';
  }
}
```

I have different sizes of membership badges which are added as a css class. The default size does not have a class.

I would like to be able to pass in a 'size' setting when I call the function from my template, e.g:

`<?php get_membership_badge('small'); ?>` or `

I have done some research into passing arguments into a function, but I'm a bit lost as to how to approach this.

I've tried the following:

```
function get_membership_badge($size) {
  $user_id = bbp_get_user_id();
  $membership_level = rcp_get_subscription($user_id);
  

  if ($membership_level === 'Community') {
    echo '';
  }

  elseif ($membership_level === 'Supporter') {
    echo '<span class="member-badge supporter ' . $size .'">Supporter</span>';
  }

  elseif ($membership_level === 'Professional') {
    echo '<span class="member-badge pro ' . $size .'">Pro</span>';
  }
}
```

and then using `<?php get_membership_badge('small'); ?>`

This causes the page to fail loading. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either I'm blind, or this should work. Are there any entries in the error log?

Comment: Is it possible you are calling `get_membership_badge` function somewhere _without_ passing a parameter? Because that won't work. You could test this by assigning a default value to the parameter, e.g `function get_membership_badge($size = '')`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I literally just figured this out before I saw your answer, thanks for the input! I feel more confident with functions now